# Unable to extract logLik from gamm model in R

Tags: r, gam

Probably a stupid question but after hours of searching for an answer I still have not found a solution. 
I have run a gamm model and the model seems to work fine. I now want to use the calculate the AIC for the model using the log likelihood calculated in the model (mod1).

The model run is as below

```
mod1<-gamm(Biomass..g. ~ Atoll + SizeCm + Depth + OuterOrLagoon,random=list(SiteID=~1),family=gaussian,data=RMI2014, method = "REML")
```

Which then after the model has run I try to get the AIC using the following code which returns the subsequent error

```
> AIC(mod1, k=2)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('gamm', 'list')"
```

Initially I thought it was wrong as I am using REML not Max Likelihood but the same error is returned when not using REML.

Is it because I have a random factor in the gamma that the error is returned?

Please help!

Cheers, Tyson

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gamm.html), the result of a `gamm` call is a list with two objects of types `gam` and `lme`.

You could get the AIC and logLik of the lme model, e.g.:

```
AIC(mod1$lme)
```

I don't know enough about gamm models to say if this is equivalent to what you're after or not (you may want to repost in [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/))